# How to type a Trait with an intermediate type to chain computations?

Tags: scala, generics, types

I would like to have a trait with two methods as follows:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def bar1(): A
  def bar2(a: A): Unit
}
```

now the problem is, I don't want the A to propagate. Say:

```
val foos: List[Foo[???]] = ...
foos.foreach({ foo =>
  val x = foo.bar1()
  // stuff
  foo.bar2(x)
})
```

the type A doesn't really matter in this code, but  I can't make compiler get along.

The type of x is dynamic, which is something I need to eliminate probably?

Is there a pattern to rewrite such a code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

```
val foos: List[Foo[_]] = ???
```

This is the same as

```
val foos: List[Foo[T] forSome { type T }] = ???
```

This makes `foos` a list of pairs. Each pair consists of a type `T` and a value of type `Foo[T]`. In the `foreach`, destructure the pair to get access to that type and name it, and also get the value:

```
foos.foreach { case foo: Foo[t] =>
  val x = foo.bar1() // inferred type t
  foo.bar2(x) // foo.bar2 wants a t, x is a t, this is well-formed
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/O0JLdEo0SdGGFIkWsYiYqA)

Note: the "pairs" vanish after type erasure. In the erased code, the `List` just contains `Foo` objects. It is necessary to explicitly destructure the pair with a `case`. If you do not, then `foo` will refer to the entire pair, and at each use the compiler will implicitly destructure it. When this happens, the two appearances of the contained type are not considered equal.

```
foos.foreach { foo =>
   val x = foo.bar1()
   foo.bar2(x)
}
```

is about the same as

```
foos.foreach { foo =>
  val x = foo match { case foo0: Foo[t] => foo0.bar1() }
  foo match { case foo0: Foo[u] => foo0.bar2(x) }
}
```

The compiler doesn't see that the `t` and the `u` are actually the same. This is because `t` is not in scope when `x` is defined, so you end up with `x: Any`, and thus you've lost type information.

Despite the existential type, this *will* work in future Scala (with the `_` syntax).

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean it doesn't matter? It matters, and a lot!

Look at this:

```
val x = foo.bar1()
// stuff
foo.bar2(x)
```

Here you needed to make sure the type of `x` is the same type `foo.bar2` needs.

You probably can do something like:

```
def process[A](data: List[Foo[A]]): Unit = 
  list.foreach { foo =>
    val x = foo.bar1()
    // stuff
    foo.bar2(x)
}
```

---

But maybe, what you wanted to say with *"dynamic"* is that you want to have a list of different types of `Foo`. So, it doesn't matter which one, because you know each foo will produce a value that it can consume, if so, you can use **type members** instead of **type parameters**:

```
trait Foo {
  type A
  def bar1(): A
  def bar2(a: A): Unit
}

def process(data: List[Foo]): Unit = 
  list.foreach { foo =>
    val x = foo.bar1()
    // stuff
    foo.bar2(x)
}
```

Comment: `List[Foo]` for `trait Foo {
  type A
  ...
}` is exactly `List[Foo[_]]` for `trait Foo[A] {
  ...
}`